# How shift data in all columns in R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, shift

I have the following R data.frame

```
df <- data.table(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  x = c(1, NA, NA),
  y = c(NA, 2, NA),
  z = c(NA, NA, 3))
```

And, I'd like to shift all data up from the "y" and all next columns without changing values order. The number of columns is variable. The final data set should be the following:

```
df_result <- data.table(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  x = c(1, NA, NA),
  y = c(2, NA, NA),
  z = c(3, NA, NA))
```

Please, help if you can!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One option is to `order` on the `NA` elements  - convert columns to logical with `is.na` - returns TRUE where there are NAs and FALSE where it is non-NA, when we `order` on that `T` comes after `F` in alphabetic order and will be last, use that index to reorder

```
library(data.table)
df[, (names(df)[-1]) := lapply(.SD, function(x)
     x[order(is.na(x))]), .SDcols = -1]
```

-output

```
> df
      id     x     y     z
   <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:     1     1     2     3
2:     2    NA    NA    NA
3:     3    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: This gives me an error "Error: unexpected input in "df[, (names(df)[-1]) := lapply(.SD, \"

Comment: @Andrii i am guessing your R version is old.  `\(x)` is a base R equivalent to `function(x)` in newer versions

Comment: Error in `[.data.table`(df1, , `:=`((names(df1)[-1]), lapply(.SD, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])),  : 
  Supplied 18 columns to be assigned 3 items. Please see NEWS for v1.12.2.

Comment: Yes. I need this for OLD version of R

Comment: @Andrii the update should work now

Comment: not works sorry

Comment: @Andrii  I thought you had only 4 columns, change `.SDcols` to `-1` i.e. select all columns except 1

Comment: I need just move UP all data in the columns without changing their order

Comment: @Andrii yes, `order` does that i.e. it is not changing the original order of non-NA because order was applied on the logical vector `is.na`

Comment: That works finally! Thanks a lot. I marked this answer as the best one!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `order` to move the non-NA values up without altering the order:

```r
sapply(df, \(x) x[order(!is.na(x), decreasing = T)])
     id  x  y  z
[1,]  1  1  3  3
[2,]  2 NA  2 NA
[3,]  3 NA NA NA
```

data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  x = c(1, NA, NA),
  y = c(3, 2, NA),
  z = c(NA, NA, 3))
```

Comment: This change order of values in columns. The order should be the same

Comment: See edit, this should work

Answer (score 2):

This will move the values up, without changing the order

```
# Helper function
f <- function(x)  c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])

# Apply to each column
df[,(names(df)):=lapply(.SD,f)]
```

@Maël shows that a better approach is calling `is.na()` only once, like this:

```
f <- function(x)  x[order(!is.na(x),decreasing=T)]
```

Comment: @Maël nicely only calls `is.na()` once.. I've noted that in an update

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your probelm:

```
library(data.table)

df[, Map(`[`, .SD, lapply(.SD,  \(x) order(as.logical(x))))]

      id     x     y     z
   <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:     1     1     2     3
2:     2    NA    NA    NA
3:     3    NA    NA    NA
```